# Screen turn off after a while because in my game there are no touch events

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am creating a game in which the player should lead the ball through mazes to the exit. I used the gyroscope sensor of the phone to do that, so the player doesn't have to touch the screen. The problem is that because there is no touch or tap event the screen of the phone turn off after some seconds. Is there a way (in Corona SDK) to prevent that ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `system.setIdleTimer( false )`
The [api](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/setIdleTimer.html) controls the idle timer of the system. If the idle timer is disabled, the screen will not be dim.